# Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin. Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead, issue?

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am having an issue with Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead, I am using Android Studio 3.0.1 and using an Android Studio project probably 2 or 3 years old, I have tried everything but couldn't find the solution. 
although have searched the entire web but still no luck solving it, and I don't see any android-apt plug-in on the code inside build.gradle

**Build.Gradle code**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.baryalitob"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

/* IMPORTANT :
 * Be careful when update dependencies, different version library may caused error */
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // google library
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.1'

    // library for api
    compile('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // ripple effect library
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: android-apt is deprecated in android studio 3 and .you have to move annotationProcessor. check this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html?#annotationProcessor_config

Comment: thanks budd let me check that.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove **apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'** from the build level gradle or if problem still persist please try removing some third party lib. this might be used by any library you using into your code.

Comment: could you please be more specific, since i am new to this, it would be great if you could give some more brief depth instructions?

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem as I used Android Studio 3.1 on macOS 10.13.

I tried to modify the gradle version here in two files:

1.`gradle-wrapper.properties`

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip`

**to**

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip`

2.`build.gradle(Module: app)`

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'`

**to**

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`

And then I solved the problem.

Comment: i had to downgrade the version of my android studio so it did work, but it was just a temporary solution since we have to work with higher more recent versions, for time being its solved.

Comment: @AzizKhan You are right,this is temporary solution,sometimes it's really useful.We need to get another better solution.